# KeyCloack с версией под докер не правильно формирует страницу логина

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, keycloak

У меня проблема с моим приложением использующем Keycloak.  У меня локально установлен Docker, а мое приложение и keyCloack запускаются в контейнерах. Дело в том, что KeyCloack не правильно формирует URL страницы логина.

вот мой docker-compose файл:

```
version: '3.2'
services:

  # Образ на основе моего Spring boot приложения
  key-cloack-graddle:    
    image: "testlocal/my-java-app-graddle:0.0.1"
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"


  key-cloack:
    image: "jboss/keycloak"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
```

Мое приложение обращается к KeyCloack по имени контейнера.   То есть, вот так выглядит конфигурация приложения (application.properties) ,

```
server.port=8081
#обращаюсь к KeyCloack по имени контейнера
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://key-cloack:8080/auth
...
```

KeyCloack в ответ возвращает страницу логина, вот по такому URL:

```
http://key-cloack:8080/auth/realms/KeyCloakTest/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=KeyCloakTestClient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fproducts&state=eca4528b-41b0-465e-9a35-c6fb6defbe83&login=true&scope=openid
```

Что не является правильным, правильно бы было вернуть такой URL :  http://localhost:8080/  вместо  http://key-cloack:8080/

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, кто сталкивался а таким.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak адаптер правильно вас редиректнул, ведь вы описали в настройках `keycloak.auth-server-url=http://key-cloack:8080/auth`. Почему вы решили, что он должен вернуть `localhost`?

Comment: Потому что по адресу http://key-cloack:8080/auth  у меня ничего не открывается, есть решение, для виндовс добавить в файл hosts, такую строку: 127.0.0.1 key-cloack. Но это костыль, хотелось бы другое решение.

Comment: Всё верно, ведь адаптер кейклока ничего не знает об окружении в котором он запускается, он просто редиректит на адрес который записан в `keycloak.auth-server-url`. Для разработки вполне можно обойтись вариантом с hosts файлом либо указывать ip машины с keycloak.